# Laravel how to properly do an ajax call

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a simple button who throw this Ajax request :

```
function myfunction(param){
        var date_debut = $('#datet_debut').val();
        var date_fin = $('#date_fin').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route('createDispo') }}',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                date_debut: name,
                date_fin: name,
            },

            success: function (data) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

But I have this error :

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

The route is generated like that :

```
Route::post('/createDispo','DepotDispoController@createDispo')->name('createDispo');
```

Here is the controller to handle the request :

```
public function createDispo(Request $request){
    $user = User::find($request->user_id);
    $disponibilite = new Disponibilite();
    $disponibilite->date_debut = $request->date_debut;
    $disponibilite->date_fin = $request->date_fin;
    $user->disponibilites()->save($disponibilite);
}
```

So, why my Ajax request doesn't work ?

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException normally means that you're sending the data by the wrong method, example sending get to a post route, or you are missing the csrf token in the meta tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to check that your method in the routes correspond to the method your are submiting.

Also, when submiting POST request Via Ajax you have to set the csrf token:

In your HTML header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Before ajax call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I have another question, do you know how can I set the fields required ? Using ajax when I click it send the request even if my field are empty and have the required attribute

Comment: please if you have other question you have to ask a new one, if this answer if the correct, please mark it. If you want to make validations to fields, you should use FormRequests, or make the validation inside the controller. If you need more information, laravel docs provide a good information

Comment: I have something strange, the solution work (for the ajax call) but it return an error, object is add to my database but the response of the ajax call go to the error function

Comment: If the answer works, then you have to vote up and mark it as correct solution